# Changing the Error Behavior of `d$y` to `with(d,y)`

Tags: r, dataframe

```
> d <- data.frame( x=rnorm(20) )
> d$y
NULL
> with(d,y)
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'y' not found
use traceback() to see the error line
```

Short of rewriting all the code that I have ever written, is there a way to *always* get 'd$y$ to abort with the same error message as 'with(d,y)' ?

Comment: `with(d,y)` is not the same as `d$y`. If you have `y` in your calling environment, then `with(d,y)` will return the value of `y`, whereas `d$y` will return `NULL`.  `$` is a special symbol and primitive function in R, so what you are asking can't really be done; even overwriting `$` with ``` `$` <- function(a, b) with(a, b) ``` won't work. (and it seems like a bad idea). Is there a reason behind you needing an error rather than a NULL?

Comment: yes, there is a simple reason.  it is my typos of variable names (often in long programs) and then wondering about wth went wrong where.  the sooner I get kicked in the head when I do something stupid, the better.  if it can't be done, it can't be done, however.

Comment: `with` and `$` are completely different things. If you want `$` to abort, first check whether `exists('y', d)`. if exists, then do `d$y` otherwise abort. But that is just for `$`.look at  `with`:  `with(3,4)`, `(\()with(4,4))()`, `(\()(\()with(5,4))())()`, `with(d, iris)` will all produce results wvwn if `iris` is not within `d`. You could also use `tibbles` to get a warning. `as_tibble(iris)$b`.

Comment: I really like the rationale of “if I fail, I want to fail early”. As @Onyambu says, switching to tidyverse will help prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: it may indeed be time to switch to tidyverse (R++)?  I only wish it was the officially endorsed future of R for everyone, too.  Feels like I am signing up for a better language, with all the positives and negatives that this entails.  Hope it will be maintained for a long time.

Comment: I see the R for Data Science book.  is this the recommended source for a book "From R to tidyverse?"  I already have a good background on R....